# Получить файл из сообщения

Tags: java, файлы, telegram-bot

Как проверить наличие и получить файл из обновления? Пишу на джаве лонг поллинг бота. Библиотека rubenlagus/TelegramBots. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение в чате разработчика библиотеки

**Получение файла**

```
 GetFile getFileRequest = new GetFile();

getFileRequest.setFileId(update.getMessage().getDocument().getFileId());

 org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.File telegramFile = 
bot.execute(getFileRequest);

File testFile = bot.downloadFile(telegramFile);
```

**Проверка на наличие файла**

```
if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasDocument())
```